# NavigateUrl="#" navigates to next page - ASP.Net Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I have following Hyperlink declared in ASP.Net.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lblPostcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("POSTCODE") %>' 
NavigateUrl="#" Target= "_blank"
onClick ='<%# String.Format("ViewGoolgeMap(\"{0}, {1}, {2}\")",Eval("ADDRESS").ToString(),Eval("TownCITY").ToString(),Eval("POSTCODE").ToString())%>' />
```

And following javascript method, invoked from above hyperlink.

```
function ViewGoolgeMap(pid) {

        window.open("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/" + pid + "", "Map" + pid, "width=500px,height=520px,left=20,top=20");

    }
```

**Actual Result** is that it is opening the popup but right after opening the popup, it navigates to an Error page saying that

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

[image: Error Message]

**Required solution** is that it should open the popup just. Nothing else needs to do.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

returning `false` in the `onClick` handler will stop the page to execute the `href`

```
function ViewGoolgeMap(pid) {
    window.open("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/" + pid + "", "Map" + pid, "width=500px,height=520px,left=20,top=20");
 return false; //Changed here

    }
```

Comment: You should also return that value in the `onclick` event handler: `onclick='<%# String.Format("return ViewGoolgeMap(...`.